# different client from different pc communicate with server using ip in java

Tags: java, ip, chat, nio

I am using `java.nio package` for my chat application. However, it can only connect different clients in the localhost only. How can I connect multiple clients from different IP addresses?

Currently I am connecting to my client using the following code:

```
InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.172");
```

I would like to be able to send messages from a client that has an IP address of 10.10.10.123 to a server which has an IP address of 10.10.10.124.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is meaningless. You don't 'connect to' clients at all, they connect to you, and `InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.172");` doesn't perform any connection function whatsoever. All you have to do is specify the target IP correctly, instead of targeting your local host.

Comment: @EJP first realize that this is a bit of code and `InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.172");(this function performs the given string will convert to an ip)` this is an argument of one of ma class. and the only thing is the ip of client should be same as Server. its working now fine ma firewall was blocking thats all thanks

Comment: I know what it does. What you wrote didn't make sense. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its the same way as you did with single pc.......

One more thing before i start.. 10.10.10.777 & 10.10.10.888 are **invalid IPs**

**IPv4 is in dotted decimal format from 0-255**

**0 - Network Address
255 - BroadCast Address**

**0 and 255 are not used for giving ip to a pc**... **use 1 - 254.**

And **try using port above 1024**, these ports are know as Well- Known ports and are used for running various service, like SMTP, FTP, HTTP, TELNET, etc.....

Thinks to be remembered....

1. **Switch off your Firewall**, or **else add an exception to the rules in firewall** for the port, where you want to run the server.
2. Create **separate thread to handle multiple client** at the Server End..

Eg :

```
The Server side code example:


public class ServerTest {

    ServerSocket s;

    public void go() {

        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(44457);

            while (true) {

                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MyCon implements Runnable {

        Socket incoming;

        public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        incoming.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String inp = null;

                boolean isDone = true;

                System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                System.out.println();
                while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(inp);
                    if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                        isDone = false;
                        s.close();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerTest().go();

    }
```

}

Comment: shall i run my server in pc1 (ip: 10.10.10.222) and my client is running in pc2 (ip: 10.10.10.333). can sever and client communicate. i changed my server code `InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.222"); ` and client `InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.333"); ` both running in different pc while running `refused to connect exception occure` in client side. is there any step i missed then please help me

Comment: client have to use the same ip of server rit so we have to change `InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.333"); ` to InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.222");

Comment: I said..the ip can be 0-254, that means 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.254

Comment: the client ip should be same as server

Comment: On client Socket s = new Socket(Server_ip, port_nos)... but both the pc should have different ip configured in its network config but in same subnet